# How to create a sprite with EaselJS?

Tags: javascript, sprite, easeljs

So I've been looking for the best way for me to create a game in Javascript, and decided that EaselJS would probably work best (If there is a better library, please do tell).

I've just hardly started, but I can't seem to get loading a sprite to work... I'm not quite sure what the problem is, as it's connecting with the canvas, it's loading the library...
Here is the javascript console error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null easeljs-0.7.1.min.j
s:12
        b._calculateFrames easeljs-0.7.1.min.js:12
        b.initialize easeljs-0.7.1.min.js:12
        a easeljs-0.7.1.min.js:12
        init index.html:3
        onload
```

So yeah... If you could help me out that'd be great... here is the src code:

```
function init() {
        var stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("demoCanvas"));
        var jazaSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet ({
            "frames": {
                "width": 15,
                "height": 16,
                "numFrames": 8,
                "regX": 0,
                "regY": 0
            },
            "animations":{
                "walkDown": [0, 1, "walkDown", 2], 
                "images": ["http://imgur.com/bLfR7TO.png"]
            }
        });
        var jaza = new createjs.Sprite(jazaSheet);
        jaza.x = 0;
        jaza.y = 0;
        jaza.goToAndPlay("walkDown");

        stage.addChild(jaza);
        Ticker.setFPS(60);
        Ticker.addListener(stage);
        stage.update();
    }
```

EDIT:
Ok so I've changed it as said, but I still can't seem to get it to show up on the canvas...

```
function init() {
var stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("demoCanvas"));
var jazaSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet ({
    "frames": {
        "width": 15,
        "height": 16,
        "numFrames": 8,
        "regX": 0,
        "regY": 0
    },
    "animations":{
        "walkDown": [0, 1, "walkDown", 2]
    },
    "images": ["http://imgur.com/bLfR7TO.png"]
});
var jaza = new createjs.Sprite(jazaSheet);
jaza.x = 100;
jaza.y = 100;
jaza.gotoAndPlay("walkDown");

stage.addChild(jaza);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
stage.update();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at it, you can see the source of the class [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/SpriteSheet.js).

Basically, you have a typo in your parameter object. 
Take the `images` object out of the `animations`

```
 var jazaSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet ({
        "frames": {
            "width": 15,
            "height": 16,
            "numFrames": 8,
            "regX": 0,
            "regY": 0
        },
        "animations":{
            "walkDown": [0, 1, "walkDown", 2]
        },
        "images": {
            ["http://imgur.com/bLfR7TO"]
        }
    });
```

Explanation:

`_calculateFrames()` function uses the private variable `images`. Row 464 creates a loop with the `array.length` as one parameter. Since the array is `null` (typo in parameter), `TypeError` exception is thrown.

Comment: ...Do you mean to say `"images":["http://imgur.com/bLfR7TO.png"]`? I think that fixed my problem though, thanks. But now I'm getting an error saying that the `Sprite` has no method go to and play. Do you know what method I should be using?

Comment: Look at the class in GitHub (/src/easeljs/display/Sprite.js line:293). Check that you type the function name correctly; "gotoAndPlay"

Comment: Did it work? Any more issues? Consider closing this question if you have an answer.